# How to find the element of this HTML link? The class_name, Xpath and css selector nothing is helping to find the element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
<div data-offset-key="80psj-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="80psj-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div>
```

I have used these three options

1. `driver.find_element_by_class_name("_1mf_1mj")`
2. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="js_1e"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div")`
3. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#js_1e > div._i-o > div.clearfix._ikh > div._4bl9 > div > div > div > div > div._5rpb > div > div > div > div")`

Comment: What about `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-offset-key="80psj-0-0"]')`?

Comment: You tried to `find_element_by_class_name` with a single class `_1mf_1mj`, but the element has two classes `_1mf` and `_1mj`.

Comment: So how to write with two classes?

Answer (score 0):

With css selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-offset-key=80psj-0-0]')
```

Or as [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) said in comments, with xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-offset-key="80psj-‌​0-0"]')
```

Comment: Both the solutions are giving error as follows:- 1) Css_selector:-              raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified.    2) XPATH:-   SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file fb.py on line 22, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._1mf._1mj")
```